# Embed a banner linking to another site

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

What I need to do is add a banner/icon to a page that is says people are a part of our organization. Kind of like the icons at the bottom of this website, the peer1 hosting one or the cc-wiki one.

I however will have my own link and image, but I was wondering if someone can help me with some code that can do this. Thanks a lot!

Edit:

Okay let me rephrase this since it was unclear the first time

I want to be able to add a code snippet that people can add to their website, that will present a banner for a "Parent" site. This banner will link back to that site, and we would be able to gather statistics of who is linking to our site as well as how often. Is this possible with simple  or  tags.

I know some HTML, but my main languages are Java, C Sharp, and Objective C, so web stuff is definitely not my forte. My boss just came up to me and asked me to do this, and I truly do not know how. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you try anything yet?  See this too... http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Yes I do know some html, but I did not know if doing something simple like an <img> or <a href> tag would add a hit to parent site, we are trying to also gather statistics for who is adding this link/image to their site, and all of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use something like:

```
<a href='http://parentsite.com/default.aspx?id=[the id of the sub-site]'>
    <img src='http://parentsite.com/images/image.aspx?id=[the id of the sub-site]' />
</a>
```

That would create a link to the parent site, and render the web page as an image. IF you then put an img tag inside the web page then it would render as the image on the sub-site and you could also log a hit for that site. Putting the id on both means that, when the img tag loads, you can record the number of times that users have loaded any page with that image on it, and you can record the number of times that users click the link.

This may not be the most efficient way of doing this, but it is one way.

Comment: what would an ID look like for this and will this work on any standard website/browser (IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox). Do you have a full url example including id. I am not very familiar with HTML or ASP

Comment: Ever so sorry for the late reply. Look at http://live.heritageartpapers.com/, a site I designed a couple of years ago. I know it doesn't look too good now but I was naive back then and now remaking the site in C#. Anyway if you look at the banner you will see that both the image and the link have an ID appended to them; this ID is stored against the company name so, when the image is loaded, the site (Gifted Options) can log an "impression". It then logs a click when the link is clicked and can be used to find out the conversion rate - how many users clicked it and how many of those placed...

Comment: ...an order. It can be very powerful to use this technique; the best thing is that it doesn't break if you disable JavaScript. You can even use this to determine how effective a banner position is on a site, for example placing it at the top for one month and at the bottom for another month, then compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<a href="your_link"><img src="your_image" /></a>
```

Comment: I knew that I should do this, but I did not know if this would show up as a hit on the source's website.